# How to Image.open a RAW (CR2) file in python?

Tags: python, image, file, raw

I have the following code for a ***.tif*** file:

```
img = Image.open("randompic.tif")

image = Jpeg()
image.encodeRGB("randompic.tif")
print(np.array_equal(image.total_bit_objects, np.asarray(Image.open('randompic.tif').convert('L'))))
```

I try to adapt it for a ***.CR2*** file :

```
img = np.fromfile('IMG_4387.CR2', "uint16")

image = Jpeg()
image.encodeRGB("IMG_4387.CR2")
print(np.array_equal(image.total_bit_objects, np.asarray(Image.open('IMG_4387.CR2').convert('L'))))
```

However, *Image.open('IMG_4387.CR2')* does not work.

Do you have any idea to fix me ?

Comment: There's 2 images in there.  You could parse [the header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3696642/reading-a-cr2-raw-canon-image-header-using-python), and try to extract them, or try https://github.com/photoshell/rawkit

Answer (score 2):

Why not try the following code. It uses simple PIL
I tried rawpy and rawkit and they had complications with Libraw.
Rawpy worked but performed a postprocessing I could not seem to understand

```
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open("File.CR2")
rgb_im = im.convert('RGB')
rgb_im.save('File.JPG')
```